# How do I print images from this model?

Tags: swift, coreml, mlmodel

I have this model.

In Mac, when an image is input, it detects objects and represents what it is.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdFBr.png

However, this model has four outputs.

I think the first output is the result.

So I converted the results into an image in Python as follows and saved the model as mlmodel.

```
import coremltools.proto.FeatureTypes_pb2 as ft

output = spec.description.output[0]
output.type.imageType.colorSpace = ft.ImageFeatureType.GRAYSCALE
output.type.imageType.height = 416
output.type.imageType.width = 416
```

In Swift, the converted results are stored in this form.

```swift
lazy var var_944: CVPixelBuffer = {
        [unowned self] in return self.provider.featureValue(for: "var_944")!.imageBufferValue
    }()!
```

After putting an image in the input, convert the output CVPixelBuffer to UIImage, and put UIImage in ImageView, no image appears.

Does anyone know the solution?

(Please understand that I used Papago because I am not good at English.)

Comment: Why you setup ft.ImageFeatureType.GRAYSCALE when output: 1, 3, 640, 640.

Need setup:
ft.ImageFeatureType.ColorSpace.Value('RGB')
And sizes: 640x640

Comment: my Model's output is MLMultiarray([1x25200x85).
So, I can't change the image to RGB.

Comment: Oh, yes it's yolo5s. Well then you can use article from this guy: 
https://rockyshikoku.medium.com/convert-yolov5-to-coreml-also-add-a-decode-layer-113408b7a848